# Configure connected monitor on a new x-screen without using xorg.conf

Tags: nvidia, gnome, graphics, xorg, xrandr

Is it possible (on Ubuntu 20.04 or newer) to configure a newly connected display (not using xorg.conf) to open a a new x-screen instead of being added to an existing x-screen?